# Why does net localgroup cause a 1312 system error?

Tags: powershell, remote-access, group-policy

I am trying to do some remote management using PowerShell 4.0, which unfortunately doesn't have the `Get-LocalGroup` function that v5.0 has. Now, I've gotten around this whole issue by using `Get-CimInstance`, but originally I was trying to just use the old-style commandline `net localgroup`.

Using `net localgroup` I was able to remotely:

- add/delete a local group: `net localgroup myGroup /[add|delete]`
- add/remove members to a group: `net localgroup myGroup User01 /[add|delete]`
- list members of a group: `net localgroup myGroup`

I seemed to be able to do everything I wanted to. However, when I tried to remotely just list the local groups using `net localgroup` I got the following error from PowerShell:

```
[VM-Test]: PS C:\> net localgroup
```

> ```
> net : System error 1312 has occured.
>     + Category Info         : NotSpecified: (System error 1312 has occurred.:String) [], RemoteException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated
> ```

I did some quick research on system error 1312 and it seems it may be related to a [security violation](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f18c20c0-4fdc-456a-998d-38b00516b213/remote-ps-session-system-error-1312-has-occurred?forum=Offtopic)?

I can see why remote management of groups could be a security issue, but as I have just shown, I can add/remove groups and users, I just can't list the groups, which seems like the **least** harmful command.

Can anyone explain why this behavior?

Comment: How are you connecting to the remote machine? `New-PSSession`?

Comment: Yes, New-PSSession

Comment: Unable to replicate. Are these machines in the same domain? The following works for me: `$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName computer -Credential user;

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {net localgroup}`

Comment: Yes, they are both a part of the same domain. They are virtual machines. Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Build 9600

Comment: I found a possible solution here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a7853ac3-6c48-4615-896a-e306067ab804/net-use-via-powershell-returning-a-specified-logon-session-does-not-exist-it-may-already-have-been?forum=winserversecurity